# Outlook - get Mail View instead Folder View

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Since yesterday, my Outlook 365 (installed on desktop) always opens with "Folder view" instead of "Mail view". I have to press "Ctrl+1" every time I open Outlook.
How can I change it? I want the default to be "Mail view".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have found a solution: I ran "Outlook.exe /resetnavpane" and it looks that "Mail view" is now a default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).